# Getting error GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Tags: opengl, macos

I am getting error code GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT when creating framebuffer on Mac (using glCheckFramebufferStatus).

I am using same code for rendering on Mac and iOS both. Maybe problem is in the buffers initialization. On iOS I am doing it this way:

```
    CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) super.layer;
    eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

    EAGLRenderingAPI api = kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2;
    m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:api];

    if (!m_context) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    if (!m_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    [self layoutIfNeeded];


    NSLog(@"Using OpenGL ES 2.0");

    [m_context
        renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER
        fromDrawable: eaglLayer];
```

Variable `m_context` is object `EAGLContext`

On the Mac this way:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormat *nsglFormat;

NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attr[] = 
{
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, m_colorBits, //16
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, m_depthBits, //16
    0 
};


[self setPostsFrameChangedNotifications: YES];

///< Next, initialize the NSOpenGLPixelFormat itself
nsglFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attr];

///< Check for errors in the creation of the NSOpenGLPixelFormat
if(!nsglFormat) { 
    NSLog(@"Invalid format... terminating."); 
    return nil; 
}


///< Now create the the CocoaGL instance, using initial frame and the NSOpenGLPixelFormat
self = [super initWithFrame:frame pixelFormat:nsglFormat];
[nsglFormat release];

///< If there was an error, we again should probably send an error message to the user
if(!self) { 
    NSLog(@"Self not created... terminating."); 
    return nil; 
}



///< Now  set this context to the current context

[[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
```

Maybe I am doing anything wrong when I initialize NSOpenGLContext. Can you see any error? Thankyou
**UPDATE**: Initialization of the OpenGL I am doing this way:

```
int m_width, m_height;


glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                             GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &m_width);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                             GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &m_height);

// Create the depth buffer.
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                      GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,
                      m_width,
                      m_height);

// Create the framebuffer object; attach the depth and color buffers.
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                          GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                          m_colorRenderbuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
                          GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                          m_depthRenderbuffer);

// Bind the color buffer for rendering.
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_colorRenderbuffer);


// Set up some GL state.
glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Could you please post your corrected code ? I tried to delete the code related to the RenderBuffer but I still get an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution. It is necessary NOT to use renderbuffer. So I have to DELETE code to init renderbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem when I tried adding a depth buffer to the sample code generated by XCode. You should add code to check for framebuffer completion:

```
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
// also check glGetError() here
```

I'm not a Mac expert, but I do remember that the position of the following call is very important:

```
[m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable: eaglLayer];
```

On iOS it needs to be before creating the color and depth components of the framebuffer.

Here is my working iOS code:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderBuffer);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderBuffer);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));

CheckOpenGLError();
```

Comment: I have got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT error. What could that mean?

Comment: The problem is on the Mac not on iOS.

Comment: and glGetRenderbufferParameteriv return width of framebuffer 0 and height 1072693248. This could be problem

Comment: You are retrieveing the render buffer width and height before you create it.

Comment: My bad... But this does not cause the error